# Script for Bits Uploads - Allow clients to upload files in IIS7/IIS7.5

Tags: script, windows-server-2008-r2, c#, iis-7, iis-7.5

I need to write a script in C#\appcmd/some other script to automatically enable the checkbox for "Allow clients to upload files" under "BITS Uploads" in virtual directory configuration

Thanks!